# Comparing each value of two rows

Tags: bash, shell

I am practicing some bash scripting on Hackerrank (recreationally). A problem that is given is that two rows of numbers represent scores of Alice and Bob respectively. Each time an element of a row has a higher score for Alice she gains a point and each time an element of a row has a higher score for Bob he gains a point (ties result in no gain). The output is the scores of Alice and Bob in that order. As an example, given this input:

```
5 6 7
3 6 10
```

The output should be:

```
1 1
```

Because 5 is greater than 3 so Alice gets a point, 6 ties 6, and 7 is less than 10 so Bob gets a point. Below I have my solution:

```
read aliceIn
read bobIn

aliceSum=0
bobSum=0
i=0
while [ $i -lt $(echo "$aliceIn" | awk '{print NF}') ]; do
    j=$((i + 1))
    aliceVal=$(echo "$aliceIn" | cut -d ' ' -f $j)
    bobVal=$(echo "$bobIn" | cut -d ' ' -f $j)
    if   [ $aliceVal -gt $bobVal ]; then ((aliceSum++));
    elif [ $bobVal -gt $aliceVal ]; then ((bobSum++));
    fi
    ((i++))
done

echo "$aliceSum $bobSum"
```

My solution does work but it is hideous. I made it by Googling how to iterate over rows, accesses elements of rows, and do some basic arithmetic in a bash script. I have a hard time believing that this is how bash scripting should be done for such a problem, I assume it is my inexperience with these kinds of bash scripts, but was unable to find relevant results for comparing two rows of values on Google

Can each element among two rows be compared in a more direct way?

Comment: @Inian, Always two rows, always the same number of elements, just bash

Comment: That said, `bash` is not the right tool for processing files, use `Awk`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the rows as arrays using the `-a` option of the `read` builtin. Then iterating over them will be much easier:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -a a
read -a b

aliceSum=0
bobSum=0
n=${#a[@]}
for (( i=0 ; i < n ; ++i ))
do
    if   [ ${a[i]} -gt ${b[i]} ]; then ((aliceSum++));
    elif [ ${b[i]} -gt ${a[i]} ]; then ((bobSum++));
    fi
done

echo "$aliceSum $bobSum"
```

Comment: I did not know about `read -a`. This is much better, thank you

Comment: instead of `if-elif` one can use `[ ${a[i]} -gt ${b[i]} ] && ((aliceSum++))`, saves a couple of keystrokes.